# ngx-loading, Angular 7. Spinner is always displayed

Tags: angular, ngx-loading

I use ngx-loading to show spinner while getting server responce. It works well: shows spinner when request sends and hides spinner when application gets server responce. But if i click on spinner's area when it is displayed, spinner does not hide, and other clicks or buttons pressing does not help.

LoadingModule is correctly imported

```
import { LoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
  LoadingModule,
  ...
```

component.html:

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading"></ngx-loading>
```

component.ts:

```
public loading = false;
...
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(term => this.loading = !!term.length),
      switchMap(term => term.length > 0
        ? this.layersService.getLayerByID(term).pipe(
          tap(data => this.searchFailed = false),
          catchError((error) => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            this.loading = false;
            this.toastr.error(JSON.stringify(error.error), 'Server error',
              {timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right', tapToDismiss: false, closeButton: true});
            return observableOf([]);
          })
        )
        : []),
      tap(() => this.loading = false));
```

Comment: could you try and reproduce the issue in a stackblitz? It could be a bug too...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ngx-loading [show]="!!loading"></ngx-loading>
```

Javascript will assume a string "false" as true as this is a *Truthy* value.
[Bang Bang](https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-bang-bang-i-shot-you-down-use-of-double-bangs-in-javascript-7c9d94446054) in javascript will get you the *Truthy* and *Falsy* value

Comment: Adding a brief explanation of how/why your code solves the problem (or even what the problem is caused by) would greatly improve your answer, and likely attract more upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it will help you, 
but try to add this lines:

```
    constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => { this.spinner.show(); }, 25);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.spinner.hide();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but NgxSpinnerService is not a part of ngx-loading module (I use version 3.0.1).